# How can I modify CSS using NodeList?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just learning JS/CSS.

Here is the site I am playing with. 
http://keysoft.keydesign-themes.com/demo1/

I want to change "text-align" attribute of a style ".pricing .pricing-row" to "left" using JavaScript.

When I change it in Chrome console (Styles) to "text-align:left" I see that it aligns rows to left but keeps buttons centered. That is what I want.

I tried in console: `document.querySelectorAll('.pricing.pricing-row')`but I can't understand how to select textAlign attribute from there. It shows a NodeList.

Also I have tried `document.getElementsByClassName('pricing-row')` but there are elements like `div.pricing-row.button-container`.

These elements are unnecessary because if I use them in a loop then buttons' alignments will be affected.
So my goal is to align only "pricing-rows" without affecting alignment of buttons or other parts.

Could you tell me please the most efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you trying to set the `style` attribute of a single element or multiple elements?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure how to do this in pure JS but it's possible with jQuery.

Basically your problem is that some of the 21 divs that have the class 'pricing-row' also have other classes, and you don't want to pick those. Well actually that helps you weed them out.

First off - in order to use jQuery in the webdev console do this:

```
$===jQuery // should prompt true
```

Now:

```
$("div[class='pricing-row'")
```

will pick only divs with this specific class. Then you can do whatever you want with them. in your case:

```
$("div[class='pricing-row'").css('text-align', 'left');
```

another option which is simply very useful to no is the jQuery not() method:

```
$(".pricing-low).not('.button-container .selector').css('text-align', 'left');
```

What happens here is that first all of the elements with the "pricing-low" class are selected, and then the not() method drops the ones that have the following extra classes. In the end the css manipulation works.